# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to fetch team data

Tags: database, flutter, api, dart, connection

my code doesn't fetch any data from my database. Here is my code from flutter side

TeamPage

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crm/models/base_url.dart';
import 'package:crm/models/team.dart';
import 'package:crm/profile/profil.dart';
import 'package:crm/screens/team/widgets/team_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../home/home_widgets/navigation_drawer_widget.dart';

class TeamPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TeamPageState createState() => _TeamPageState();
}

class _TeamPageState extends State<TeamPage> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKEY = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  late Future<List<Team>> _teamData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _teamData = fetchTeams();
  }

  Future<List<Team>> fetchTeams() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('${BaseUrl.BASE_URL}/flutter-api/database'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return data.map((json) => Team.fromJson(json)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch team data');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKEY,
      drawer: NavigationDrawerWidget(),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 90,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.menu_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () =>
                          _scaffoldKEY.currentState?.openDrawer(),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Team",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.add_alert_outlined,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => PorfilePage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.045,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.87,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04,
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.search_outlined, color: Colors.white),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.teal.shade200,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      offset: Offset(1, 1),
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
              ),
             FutureBuilder<List<Team>>(
        future: fetchTeams(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final List<Team> teams = snapshot.data!;

            return TeamWidget(team: teams.first);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }

          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
            ])
            )
            )
            );
  }}
```

---

TeamWidget

```
import 'package:crm/models/team.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';

import '../../../../route/route_helper.dart';

class TeamWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Team team;

  TeamWidget({required this.team});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.8,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child:   ListView.builder(
          itemCount:9,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: ListTile(
                
                       title: Container(
              
                       height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.15,
                       width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8 ,
                   child: Row(
                    
                     children: [
                    Column( 
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.06,),  
                    
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            
                    SizedBox( width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.02 ,),
                            CircleAvatar(
                                     radius: 25,
                                     backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/1.png'),
                                     
                                   ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox( width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.03 ,),
                    VerticalDivider(
                      color: Colors.black26,  //color of divider
                      width: 1, //width space of divider
                      thickness: 1, //thickness of divier line
                      indent: 8, //Spacing at the top of divider.
                      endIndent: 8, //Spacing at the bottom of divider.
                    ),
                    SizedBox( width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.03 ,),
                                      
                       Column(
                         children: [
                             SizedBox(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.03 ,),
                             SizedBox(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.05,),
                             Text('Name: ${team.name}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                       SizedBox( width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.03 ,),
                         Text('Email: ${team.email}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.grey.shade400,),),
              
                       SizedBox( width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.03 ,),
            
                         Text('Phone : ${team.phone }',style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black54,fontSize: 13 ),)
                 
                         ],
                       ),
                    Spacer(),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.055,),  
                          Icon(Icons.remove_circle,color: Colors.red,)
                        ],
                      ),
                        SizedBox( width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.03 ,),
                     
                     ],
                   ),
            
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       color:Colors.white,
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                       boxShadow: [
                         BoxShadow(
                             blurRadius: 10,
                             spreadRadius: 5,
                             offset: Offset(1, 1),
                             color:Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1)
                         )
                       ]
                   ),
                 ),
              ),
            );
    
          
          }
         ),
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color:Colors.grey.shade100,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20),topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
           ),
           
           ),
    );
       }
}
```

Class Team

```
class Team {
  late final int id;
  late final String name;
  late final String email;
  late final double phone;

  Team({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.phone,
  });

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Team(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      email: json['email'],
      phone: json['phone'],
    );
  }
}
```

---

buse_url

```
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

class BaseUrl {
  static String BASE_URL = "http://mermez.site/flutter-api";
}
```

Thank you

as
uuuuuasduuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuasd uuuuuuuuuu uusdauuuuuuuuusaduu uuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuadsuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu  uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu asuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuu uuuuuuusdauuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuu uuudauuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuusauuuuuuuuuuuud
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuduuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu u uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuu uuuuuudsauuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu uusdauuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

---

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the request to the server itself. I can assume that you are accessing the wrong url.

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('${BaseUrl.BASE_URL}/flutter-api/database'));
```

Your **BASE_URL** is `"http://mermez.site/flutter-api"`

It means that all your requests go to `"http://mermez.site/flutter-api/flutter-api/database"`